# How to use BeautifulSoup to get content inside over-line tags

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I would like to extract the content("_The_important_content_") from an HTML snippet as follows:

```
<div
                                            class="
                                            a:2
                                            c:gray
                                            m:da
                                        "
                                    >
                                         _The_important_content_
                                    </div>
```

My code is just:

```
for i in soup.findAll('div', class_="a:2 c:gray m:da"):
    print(i.text)
```

But because the "class" field contains new line symbols and is expanded to multiple line so that BeautifulSoup cannot match, the code returns nothing. How can I specify the correct class field and get the content?

There are many  tags with the same "class" value and other "class" value but I want to extract the contents from the  tags with that specific "class" value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html='''
<div
            class="
            a:2
            c:gray
            m:da
        "
    >
         _The_important_content_
    </div>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
item = soup.select("[class^=]")[0].text
print(item.strip())
```

Result:

```
_The_important_content_
```

Comment: Just think, how is it possible for anyone to create an expression without seeing whatever the html elements are?